# How can I set CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to Ninja?

Tags: makefile, cmake, ninja

I'm a newbie to CMake and am trying to understand how to configure CMake to use Ninja as the build tool. The specific problem I'm having is I'm trying to install YouCompleteMe plugin for vim using their install.py. I get the following error:

```
Searching Python 3.8 libraries...
Found Python library: /usr/lib64/libpython3.8.so
Found Python headers folder: /usr/include/python3.8
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/ycm_build__dy3xdvd/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ERROR: the build failed.
```

After looking similar errors up on the internet I realise that I can fix this by installing Make. But, I'm wondering if I can actually use Ninja instead of Make which I have already installed and is in the path. Is there a way I can set `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` to my Ninja installation so that I can get past this error or do I have to use Make because `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` can only be set from within the project?

EDIT:

When I say set the `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`, I mean at the machine level like an environment variable. Not by modifying the build definition files in the actual project I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set the environment variable [`CMAKE_GENERATOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html#envvar:CMAKE_GENERATOR) to `Ninja`. CMake will read this variable to choose the generator, rather than picking the default "Unix Makefiles" you are seeing. This is useful when you are not calling `cmake` directly and cannot pass the `-G` command line option to set the generator.

The `CMAKE_GENERATOR` variable will end up setting the [`CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) variable for you, so you should not have to modify this manually.

Comment: I set an environment variable `export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja` globally and verified that it's set. But I still get the same error. When I check `cmake --help`, I see that the default generator is still "Unix Makefiles".

Comment: @kovac The CMake help menu probably won't change based on system environment variables, so that will likely *always* say "Unix Makefiles" in your environment. Setting the environment variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR` will override the default value. You should remove the CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt`) before re-running CMake so the old configuration is not accidentally used.